# log4j used as property under maven-surefire-plugin , Do I need to change anything as log4j has vulnerability in its version?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, java-8, log4j

`log4j` used as property under `maven-surefire-plugin` , Do I need to change anything as log4j has vulnerability in its version? If yes then how to know which version is used by this plugin and how do I update the same.

Plugin configuration goes like this, also my plugin version is 2.12

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>loggerPath</name>
                            <value>conf/log4j.properties</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <argLine>-Xms512m -Xmx1500m</argLine>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <forkMode>pertest</forkMode>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like it is being made available for your test code.  `loggerPath` used anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it is even working for you. I didn't see any usage of `loggerPath` property inside the plugin.
Does it create a proper appender in your tests?

I think you can easily remove `systemProperties` from here if tests generate logs in the same way they do now.